# how to remove duplicate charecter strictly using regexp in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

How to remove duplicate characters in a string strictly using regexp in TCL?
e.g., I have a string like this `aabbcddeffghh` and I need only characters that are "`abcdefgh`". I tried with `lsort unique`, i am able to get unique characters:

```
join [lsort -unique [split $mystring {}]]
```

but i need using `regexp` command only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't remove all non-consecutive double characters from a string with just Tcl's `regsub` command. It doesn't support access to back-references in lookahead sequences, which means that any scheme for removal will necessarily run into problems with overlapping match regions.

The simplest fix is to wrap in a `while` loop (with an empty body), using the fact that `regsub` will return the number of substitutions performed when it's given a variable to store the result in (last argument to it below):

```
set str "mississippi mud pie"
while {[regsub -all {(.)(.*)\1+} $str {\1\2} str]} {}
puts $str;          # Prints "misp ude"
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try this one:**

```
regsub -linestop -lineanchor -all {([a-z])\1+} $subject {\1} result
```

or

```
regsub -linestop -nocase -lineanchor -all {([a-z])\1+} $subject {\1} result
```

**Explanation**

```
{
(           # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [a-z]       # Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z”
)
\1          # Match the same text as most recently matched by capturing group number 1
   +           # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
}
```

Comment: i tried it works above example, but i tried with anther example it did not works me, I tried with this example                        % set subject "development"
development
% regsub -linestop -lineanchor -all {([a-z])\1+} $subject {\1} result
0
% puts $result
development

Comment: Could you provide the sample you tried to match with the pattern?

Comment: I tried with this pattern "development" here i need to remove 'e' but the above regexp is not working

Comment: Within word `development`, `e` never comes two or more consecutive times, hence that pattern would not work. If you need any other doubt let me know

Comment: Now my doubt is i need to remove 'e' in development pattern, I need to remove character that are not consecutive repeat in the pattern

Comment: Why the `-linestop -lineanchor` options?

Comment: @Malli: You may try ``regsub -nocase -all {([a-z])([a-z]*?)\1+} $subject {\1\2} result``.

Comment: @DonalFellows: No basic need for using those options. May be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

```
regsub -all {(.)(?=.*\1)} $subject {} result
```

It uses a look-ahead to check if there are any more instances of the character. If there are, it removes the character.

You will always retain the last character. It is not possible to do look-behinds in TCL without extra libraries.

More information about look-arounds: [Regex tutorial - Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Width Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

---

Edit: Hmmm... Seems to be a bug with backreferences in Tcl 8.5. `{(.).*\1}` matches, but not `{(.)(?=.*\1)}`. It complains about `Invalid backreference number`. I can't see any solution to this without a backreference inside a look-ahead.

It might just be the version i tested it on ([ideone.com/pFS0Q](http://ideone.com/pFS0Q)). I can't find any other version of a Tcl interpreter online to test.